# How to optimize regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to run the following regex `^(.*\s)*(([A-Z]{2,3}(?:-[0-9]+){3}))((\s)+.*)?$`, but I get timeout for string that is about 100+ characters. I ran this regex in JS, and I also tried to run it in regex101.com.

What I am trying to match is 'ABC-12312-121231-12312', and it can be started and followed by any strings.

Here is my JS Code:

```
const regexTransaction   = /^(.*\s)*(([A-Z]{2,3}(?:-[0-9]+){3}))((\s)+.*)?$/
var resTransaction       = new RegExp(regexTransaction,'g').exec(encodedMsg)

console.log(resTransaction)
```

I really appreciate for any help.

Comment: Do you need to capture anything within the string, or just the match the entire sequence?

Comment: @rayhatfield I want to match the entire sequence, but this sequence `ABC-1234-1234-1234` can be followed by anything. It can also be started with anything, e.g. "Lorem ABC-1234-1234-1234 lorem".

Comment: Is it always 2-3 alpha - 5 digits - 6 digits - 5 digits?

Comment: @rayhatfield It will be 2-3 alpha - any number of digits - any number of digits - any number of digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These both seem reasonably performant. The first assumes a known number of digits in each chunk (5, 6, 5). The second is a cleaned up version of your original regex, which accepts 3 sequences of any number of digits delimited by hyphens.

```js
// assumes ABC - 5 digits - 6 digits - 5 digits
const regex = /([A-Z]{2,3}-[\d]{5}-[\d]{6}-[\d]{5})/g;

// your original regex with unnecessary stuff stripped out.
// notice that this captures the second item with 999 appended that the first expression doesn't get.
const regex2 = /([A-Z]{2,3}(?:-[0-9]+){3})/g;

const input = "asfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312999afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12345afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-99999-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfdsasfsfdasABC-12312-121231-12312afsasfsdfds";

console.log(input.match(regex));
console.log(input.match(regex2));
```